# English translation of the Nepali word, "chakari"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been trying to find the exact English word for a Nepali word "chakari" which means to serve a person hoping to get favour/benefit from him if he is *satisfied/happy* with with the service provided.

The service provided is not related with slavery. The service provider provides the service of his own free will.

Comment: In what sort of setting would someone display "chakari"? Does it have a religious/spiritual connotation? Or is it performed for material gain?

Comment: There is an idiom ["you scratch my back and I'll scratch yours"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+scratch+my+back+and+I'll+scratch+yours); it sounds like you looking for something like "I'll scratch your back, you scratch mine". All I can think of is a [**'quid pro quo'**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quid_pro_quo) arrangement, but the 'favour in return' is pretty much agreed in advance, and certainly expected.

Comment: It is something practiced in nepal long ago. People used to go to wealthiest people and tend to help them or make happy to get something in return. It is applied for material gain in common

Comment: @jhc idiom  seems interesting. But I can't use it in current scenario

Comment: We sometimes use the word "goodwill" to refer to the possibility that because of good reputation and/or past good deeds, some profit may (but may not) come to us.  E.g., you might mow your neighbor's lawn to cultivate her "goodwill" -- you don't expect a direct money payment but maybe she will do something nice for you today.  Or you give a good customer a free item to strengthen their loyalty to your business.  Indeed "goodwill" is commonly valued as part of a business which has built up a reputation behind its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a verb, I don't think there is a suitable one. You have to use "*do something in hope of reciprocation*".

[Reciprocation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocation) [Merriam-Webster] means:

> a return in kind or of like value

[Give-and-take](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give%20and%20take) [Merriam-Webster] can also be used in place of reciprocation as it means:

> the process by which people reach an agreement with each other by
>   giving up something that was wanted and agreeing to some of the things
>   wanted by the other person

You can't use the verb [*reciprocate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reciprocate) [Wiktionary] as it means:

> To give something in response.

Comment: @SamitRimal Happy it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this word would have too negative of a connotation, but *sycophancy* is a word that comes to mind. A sycophant praises someone in power in the hopes of gaining their approval. It is strongly negative, though.

*Servile* or *subservient* are other adjectives that describe someone who serves and is willingly submissive to others, but they don't have the connotation of expecting something in return in the way that a sycophantic person might.

Comment: I think Servile is related to  slavery as far I know

Comment: No, it describes a person who is willingly obedient and submissive in nature. It just has the same root word as "servant."

Comment: It is not a servant because there is no return guarantee. Servant get return in any form for service provided.  i think it is used for household works. Correct me if I am wrong. English is my second language.

Comment: @SamitRimal after seeing more information about "chakari," I see that "servile" is not an appropriate translation, but so you know, "servile" doesn't have to describe a servant. It is saying someone is **like** a servant in their eagerness to serve someone else. Like I said in my original answer, it doesn't convey that the person expects something in return, so it's not the best translation.